# Count iterations that have occured in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to find out if there is a way to count the number of iterations that have occurred with the code below:

```
with open(filename1) as file1, open(filename2) as file2:
    for line1, line2 in zip(file1, file2):
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that using `enumerate`:

```
with open(filename1) as file1, open(filename2) as file2:
    for i, (line1, line2) in enumerate(zip(file1, file2)):
```

Here `i` will be the number of iterations that you have run. More correctly, `i` will be the index of `line1` and `line2` in the zipped list which for your purpose is essentially the same. Note however that on the first iteration, `i` will be `0` not `1`. More generally, on the `nth` iteration, the value of `i` will be `n-1`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and for explaining your response.